# How to load json data in nuxt.js

Tags: json, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have three data in json like title, description and author of book. I want to make different pages for different books in which all data is included. How can I make only one page template and plug json data into page to generate all other pages with different url. I may change that data when required thus updating data of generated page is required.I am using nuxt spa and static site is generated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Nginx server, then making small change in nginx server configuration as described in the VueRouter guide.

Basically, whenever a new dynamic route is accessed , it falls back on the main index.html file which will handle the dynamic params and renders the page after api calls etc.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

source: [https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2177](http://%20https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2177)